# Why don't API calls to /search get all matching results?

Tags: python, huggingface-datasets

I'm trying to find rows in some HuggingFace datasets which have a certain word or phrase in a specific column (e.g., "output"). I've written some basic Python code to do this, but I noticed an issue at the API level when trying to get a slice of the data that contains every row with one of the words from my phrase. (As I understand it, with the API you can't even search for rows that contain both words—only OR searching.)

Specifically, when making calls to the [HuggingFace Datasets-server API](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets-server/search) `/search` endpoint:

- A search for *used*, a word which we'd expect to see frequently in the data: https://datasets-server.huggingface.co/search?dataset=teknium%2FGPT4-LLM-Cleaned&config=default&split=train&offset=0&length=100&query=used

  - Returns very few results (14 rows)
  - Searching for *use* instead returns the same results
- A search for *spices*, an arbitrary less common word: https://datasets-server.huggingface.co/search?dataset=teknium%2FGPT4-LLM-Cleaned&config=default&split=train&&offset=0&length=100&query=spices

  - Returns more matches for "used" (or "use") than the first API call (I didn't count how many rows that is, but it certainly returns new rows that weren't in the first query)

I thought these searches would return all the rows with the specified word (and as a bonus, stemming forms like *used* to *use*) in any column. (Note that "num_rows_total" at the end shows how many total rows are found for each search, but the amount per page is limited to 100.) However, as you can see, I didn't get all the rows containing "used" in the first search and as a result I wonder if any of the searches made through this type of call are actually returning all the relevant results (which is essential).

I've noticed this same type of behavior with other datasets too. Often no rows are returned for searches that I know should return rows. They're all large datasets (10k to 1m rows) which were "Auto-converted to Parquet" according to their listings on the HuggingFace website.

I'd like to avoid looping over every row in the entire dataset for every phrase that I decide to look up this way, and I don't want to download these datasets either. Is there a modification that I can make to the API call to make it work? Or maybe a different call would work better?

Comment: documentation show code with `API_TOKEN` but you run normal link. Maybe you have to register and get `API_TOKEN` to get more results.

Comment: @furas The results seem to be the same with an API token. (Obviously, I did not spend money on one, however.) Also, the [docs](https://huggingface.co/docs/hub/security-tokens) say only this: "read: tokens with this role can only be used to provide read access to repositories you could read. That includes public and private repositories that you, or an organization you’re a member of, own. Use this role if you only need to read content from the Hugging Face Hub (e.g. when downloading private models or doing inference)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lines recently added to [the documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets-server/search) explain:

> If the result has `partial: true` it means that the search couldn’t be run on the full dataset because it’s too big.
>
> Indeed, the indexing for `/search` can be partial if the dataset is bigger than 5GB. In that case, it only uses the first 5GB.

The exact same thing is true of `/filter`, and the numbers returned by `/size` are affected as well.